# How to start a script after login using gdm?

Tags: arch-linux, login, xmonad, gdm3, xinit

I am using arch linux with xmonad, and I login using gdm, but to make xmonad work properly I have to run a script directly after login (actually I want to run `.xinitrc` after login using gdm to set some configuration).so, How it is possible ro run a bash script immediatly after login.

I tried several ways such as editing

```
/etc/gdm/PostLogin/Default
```

thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Most display managers will, upon successful login, look for and source a file called `~/.xsession`. This is where you put your X session customisations, much as you put your shell customisations in, for example, `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zprofile`

Note that the file `~/.xinitrc` is sourced by `startx`, and not by default by display managers.

Answer (score -1):

To execute a script/command after you log in you can use **~/.bash_profile** or **~/.bash_login**. This method should normally be agnostic of how you logged in (e.g. whether you did a terminal login or logged in through a display/login manager). There's also **~/.bash_logout** for commands after you log off.

example:

```
#
# ~/.bash_profile
#

[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc

exec startx
```

Should work to start X and execute .xinitrc as soon as you log in.

Please refer to [the arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/bash) for more info if you run into problems.

Comment: According to arch wiki I have to use ~./bashrc, but it did not function properly, after running it, I will not be able to open the terminal

Comment: yes that's right, it applies on every login...

Do you need to open the terminal? Can't you just use your GUI terminal in X?

Comment: I am using gnome terminal and X terminal

Comment: Yes those will work fine since you have already logged in (.bash_profile is only applied when you log in, not after you have already logged in. So basically for this to happen again you'd have to press CTRL+ALT+F2 to go to tty2 and log in again and that would run .bash_profile again)

Comment: Do you think appending & at the the end of each line in .xinitrc can cause this problem

Comment: @husseinhoudrouge what problem? It wouldn't cause any problems I'm aware of (I do this myself, except for the last line which is to execute the window manager; I think you actually have to do it)

Also you are using .bash_profile right? I think .bashrc is applied everytime you open a terminal, it's not the same as every login. .bash_profile is only once per login.